# Is the inverse of projection idempotent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

The projection operator is idempotent so that $\hat{p}\hat{p}\hat{A}\hat{p}\hat{p}=\hat{p}\hat{A}\hat{p}$. Is the following relation also correct? $$ 
\hat{p} \left(\frac{1}{\hat{p}\hat{A}\hat{p}}\right)\hat{p}=\hat{p}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{A}}\right)\hat{p}
 $$

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are right. But to see why the inverse of the projection operator isn't an operator, look at this simple example from an ordinary $2$D vector space. Let $\hat{P}$ be the projection of a vector onto the x axis.

$$\hat{P}\bigl{[}(1,1)\bigr{]} = \hat{P}\bigl{[}(1,2)\bigr{]} = (1,0)$$

So what is $\hat{P}^{-1}\bigl{[}(1,0)\bigr{]}?$ It can go more than one place.

What is $\hat{P}^{-1}\bigl{[}(1,1)\bigr{]}?$ $\hat{P}$ doesn't send any vector to $(1,1)$, so $\hat{P}^{-1}$ can't send it back anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The operator
$$
\hat{B} = \frac{1}{\hat{p}\hat{A}\hat{p}}
$$
is not generally well-defined.  To see this, note that for $\hat{B}$ to be a well-defined inverse, we would want to have
$$
\hat{B} \left[ \hat{p} \hat{A} \hat{p} \mathbf{v} \right] = \mathbf{v}.
$$
But if $\mathbf{v} \neq 0$ is such that $\hat{p} \mathbf{v} = 0$ then we will have
$$
\hat{B} \left[ \hat{p} \hat{A} \hat{p} \mathbf{v} \right] = \hat{B} \left[ \hat{p} \hat{A} \mathbf{0} \right]= \mathbf{0}
$$
automatically.  And such a $\mathbf{v}$ exists for "most" projection operators;  just pick $\mathbf{v}$ to lie in the subspace of vectors orthogonal to the space onto which $\hat{p}$ is projecting.  (The only "loophole" is if this orthogonal subspace is trivial, but in this case $\hat{p}$ is the identity operator.)

Answer (score 2):

If it is idempotent, its eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$ since the eigenvalue must satisfy $\lambda^2=\lambda$.  Unless you have the identity (which is idempotent), how do you define the inverse, which would have $1/\lambda$? as an eigenvalue?

Projections are examples of idempotent operators.  If you project a vector on the $\hat x$ axis, what is the meaning of an inverse projection?  In 2d, the projection on $\hat x$ has matrix form
$$
\Pi_x=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&0\end{array}\right)
$$
and it is clear this idempotent matrix does not have an invervse.

Physically, any vector $a\hat x+b\hat y$ projects to $a\hat x$ and doing this twice projects $a\hat x+b\hat y$ to $a\hat x$ then again to $a\hat x$.  How do you undo this?  How can you know if the outcome of your projection $a\hat x$ is from $a\hat x+b\hat y$ or $a\hat x+c\hat y$?

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out implicitly by the previous excellent answers already that one important question to answer in the beginning of looking for an inverse to an operator $\hat{A} $ is to check whether $\hat{A} : U\rightarrow V$ is at most bijective.

This means that any point in the image space $v\in V$ has at most one element in the origin space $u\in U$ such that $\hat{A}(u)=v $. If this condition does not hold, as pointed out above for the projection operator, there is no way of guaranteeing that the inverse operator exists.

It is assumed here that $\hat{A} $ is not only a mere ( possibly even multivalued) mapping but kind of a function.

You can imagine it like this: If several elements $u_1 \dots  u_n$ are mapped to the same element v via $\hat{A} $, then the inverse Operator would need additional information from nowhere to identify the correct original element, as the inverse operator is intended to not only be a mapping but an operator which is somewhat stronger of a condition on $\hat{A} $.